# Use a YAML variable template into a step template

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use variables from `TST-Variables.yml` into `adf_deploy.yaml`. I tried the below, I see no syntax error but an error that `$(azureResourceManagerConnection)` does not exist

```
- ${{ if in(parameters.Environment, 'Auto', 'Test') }}:
  - stage: DeployTST
    displayName: 'ARM Template deployment on TST environment'   
    jobs:
    - job:
      displayName: 'Deployment steps:'
      variables:
      - template: /pipeline/variables/TST-Variables.yml
      steps:
      - template: /DataFactory/build/adf_deploy.yaml
        parameters:
              Environment: Test
```

**TST-Variables.yml**

```
variables:

  # Data Factory
  - name: DataFactoryName
    value: dqe01-t-01-adf
  - name: azureResourceManagerConnection
    value: dqe01-t-rg
  - name: resourceGroupName
    value: dqe01-t-rg
(...)
```

**adf_deploy.yaml**

```
(...)
# Deploy
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: $(azureResourceManagerConnection)
    subscriptionId: $(SubscriptionId)
    resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/DataFactory/build/ArmTemplate/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/DataFactory/build/ArmTemplate/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
(...)
```

Comment: If doing Data Factory have working examples of a [build template](https://github.com/JFolberth/TheYAMLPipelineOne/blob/main/stages/adf_build_stage.yml) and a [deploy template](https://github.com/JFolberth/TheYAMLPipelineOne/blob/main/stages/adf_deploy_stage.yml) if you will help. They are configured similar to what you are looking for with a pipeline in a [separate repo](https://github.com/JFolberth/adf_pipelines_yaml_ci_cd/blob/main/YAML/adf_pipelines_template.yml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access the variable from the template file, you need to use the `variables` keyword, in your case `$(variables.azureResourceManagerConnection)`.

You can find more info [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/variables-template?view=azure-pipelines).